# InstagramAPI: doesn't return a list of followers

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I try to get list of followers and followings, but it doesn't returns it.

I have registered the app with

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&response_type=token&scope=public_content+follower_list
```

Next I try to get my followers

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by.json?access_token=access_token
```

But it returns me

```
{"pagination": {}, "data": [], "meta": {"code": 200}}
```

What Do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are in sandbox mode, so you will only get users who are in your sandbox list, add one of your followers to sandbox, then only that user will show up in response. Once you get reviewed and go live, all users will show up.

Comment: What does GET REVIEWED AND GO LIVE mean?

Comment: In documentation - Users will need to accept the invitation to become sandbox users. You can invite up to 10 users and each user can be invited to 5 apps. - I should invite person to get info about him? But if I need to get info from many users?

Comment: if you want to get access to all users other than the sandbox users, you have complete app, submit for review and then if u get approved, you have to go live, then you will have API access to all data